# Clean way to join tuples to string

Tags: python, string, tuples

Is there a cleaner, more Pythonic way to perform the following on a list of tuple values:

```
list_stops = [(-122.4079,37.78356),
              (-122.404,37.782)]
str_join = ''
for i in list_stops:
    coords_str = str(i[0]) + ',' + str(i[1]) + ';'
    str_join = str_join + coords_str

final_str = str_join[:-1]
```

I need to obtain a string that joins all tuple values, but the pairs need to be separated by a ';' sign.
Example output for my '`final_str`':

```
-122.4079,37.78356;-122.404,37.782
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can even try a list comprehenssion as below:

```
';'.join([','.join([str(x) for x in y]) for y in list_stops])
o/p: '-122.4079,37.78356;-122.404,37.782
#Explanation
#1st i make something like ['-122.4079,37.78356', '-122.404,37.782'] by
#all inner tuples become ',' joined
#then ';' join those valuse
```

breaking into 2 steps for more clarity

```
list_1 = [','.join([str(x) for x in y]) for y in list_stops]
#['-122.4079,37.78356', '-122.404,37.782']
req_string = ';'.join(list_1)
#'-122.4079,37.78356;-122.404,37.782'
```

Comment: To future readers: note that `';'.join([','.join([str(x) for x in y]) for y in list_stops])` is faster and more efficient than `';'.join(','.join(str(x) for x in y) for y in list_stops)` because `.join` has to scan the iterable its joining twice: the first scan determines the size of the output string, the second scan builds the string. So if you pass it a generator it has to run the generator into a list before it can perform its scans.

Comment: Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 3):

Chain two `str.join`, notice the use of `map` necesary for transforming the values to `string`:

```
list_stops = [(-122.4079,37.78356),
              (-122.404,37.782)]
";".join(",".join(map(str, x)) for x in list_stops)

'-122.4079,37.78356;-122.404,37.782'
```

Comment: why exactly do you need the `map` function? Wouldn't it also be possible with `str(x)`?

Comment: @Praind Try it! `str(x)` returns a string of the whole tuple, eg `'(-122.404, 37.782)'`.

Answer (score 2):

If they are always just pairs:

```
list_stops = [(-122.4079, 37.78356), (-122.404, 37.782)]
final_str = ';'.join('{},{}'.format(p1, p2) for p1, p2 in list_stops)

print final_str
```

Giving you:

```
-122.4079,37.78356;-122.404,37.782
```

If you need to ensure that only pairs are used, this approach would stop with a `ValueError` if an incorrect number of arguments was given which could be useful.